# how to establish in models file that a django model should be defined as NOT NULL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, models

In my models.py file I would like a way to explicitly state that certain fields in my model should be defined as NOT NULL such that the MySQL code would be

```
CREATE TABLE Minion_job(MyColumn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ...., ....);
```

Instead of what it does right now which is

```
CREATE TABLE Minion_job(MyColumn VARCHAR(50), ...., ....);
```

I was able to find that models have special optional fields, most notably in this case blank and null, for these kinds of modifications but I wasn't able to figure out based on my googling how to implement those fields (or otherwise achieve the desired effect) in my models.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean:

```
class sth(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null = False, blank = False)
```

:) Glad that I could help.

Comment: That's what I meant, I was unsure how to go about putting that in.

Answer (score 1):

Add `null=False` to you Field definition, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    your_char_field = Models.CharField(null=False)
    ...
```